# How to implement something like <input type="radio" onclick="if(this.checked){myFunction()}"> by using zf2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form-element, zfcuser

I am using zf2 framework. So that i need to implement something like,

i have tried to find it by search it on internet but i could not find any tutorials about this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
    $element = new Element\Radio('name');
    $element->setAttribute('onClick', 'if(this.checked){myFunction()}');
```